# php gettext for string in json

Tags: php, gettext

how do i implement the gettext echo _("") for 'message' below?

```
$output = array(
                'returnCode'    => '0',
                'message'   => "Sorry, an error has occured. Please try again."
            );
echo json_encode($output);
```

i tried

```
$output = array(
                    'returnCode'    => '0',
                    'message'   => echo _("Sorry, an error has occured. Please try again.")
                );
```

but of course it returns an error

Comment: thanks.. anyway I just noticed that too actually.. proof that I need some sleep... anyway why don't u put your comment as answer? at least I can mark it

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to echo the index `message` you can do this:

```
$output = array(
            'returnCode'    => '0',
            'message'   => "Sorry, an error has occured. Please try again."
        );

$message = $output['message'];

echo $message; //output: Sorry, an error has occured. Please try again.
```

echo in json format:

```
echo json_encode($message);
```

Depend of what you will do you should make an [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) to the variable before encode to json